# Java 8 stream a Collection and add only a specific field of the filtered values to a List of String

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a collection of Account objects. I would like to stream through this collection and filter based on if the price is greater than 100. Then add only those account ids to a List

This is what I have using forEach

```
 List<String> filteredAcctList = new ArrayList<String>()
  forEach(Account acct:accountList){
      if(acct.getPrice() >100){
         filteredAcctList.add(acct.getAccountId())
       }
  }
```

I am trying to accomplish the same using the Java 8 stream but not sure how to create an ArrayList  of just the account Ids.

Comment: Pretty basic streamage: `accountList.stream().filter(acct -> acct.getPrice() > 100).map(Account::getAccountId).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: @shmosel, if the filter logic is in a method, say isAcctPriceMoreThan100 then can I just replace the acct.getPrice() with the call to the method?

Comment: Sure. You could also use a method reference, e.g., `.filter(Account::isPriceMoreThan100)`

Comment: Great! Thank you!! I am trying to experiment filtering against a helper method in the class which does some boundary checks etc. So I will replace the filter logic as so:                              filter(acct ->checkValues(acct.getPrice())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `map` in order to "map" your `Account` items into `String`.

```
List<String> filteredAccList = 
    accountList
        .stream()
        .filter(a -> a.getPrice() > 100)
        .map(Account::getAccountId)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```